# How do I display values from sql in python, and display it using my UI design which is in ReactJS?

Tags: python, mysql, reactjs, mysql-connector-python

So I am working on a project that needs to display only SOME values from a database, I got the queries to get these values from SQL without any issues, all I want to know is how do I get python to keep getting the next values of whatever I needed and display them in JavaScript UI? My UI design looks like this:

[image]

How do I get the next boxes to display the next student name and reason of visit?

My database contains FirstName, LastName, MobileNumber, Gender, Passport, Parents, Emergency Contact, Reason of Visit, I know how to get the values individually and store them in python variables, but how do I get it to work in my JavaScript UI?

Comment: You can show some of your code, it's hard to help if we don't see what you are currently doing.

Comment: Hey @PierreMonier, i dont have any code as of yet, just the UI i designed in XD, should i export it into reactjs?